# Undefined reference to `DAQmxCreateTask@8 not able to link DLL VS codes

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, dll

Im using VS codes to build a C program, i need to use a third party DLL from National instruments
I have included the .h file in my program "NIDAQmx.h", but still when i run the program, the functions in this DLL is undefined
How can i link this DLL to my code?

my code goes like this

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include"C:\Program Files (x86)\National Instruments\Shared\ExternalCompilerSupport\C\include\NIDAQmx.h"

TaskHandle taskHandle=0;
int ret=0;

    void main()
{
    printf("Hello world");
    ret=DAQmxCreateTask("task",&taskHandle);
    printf("Return for creating task is %d\n",ret);
    DAQmxStopTask (taskHandle);
    DAQmxClearTask(taskHandle);
    printf("Task closed ");

}`
```

this is my console output

```
[Running] cd "d:\VSCODES\" && gcc test.c -o test && "d:\VSCODES      \"test C:\Users\rahul\AppData\Local\Temp\ccuN1dmO.o:test.c:(.text+0x32):       

undefined reference to `DAQmxCreateTask@8'

C:\Users\rahul\AppData\Local\Temp\ccuN1dmO.o:test.c:(.text+0x5c):        undefined reference to `DAQmxStopTask@4'

C:\Users\rahul\AppData\Local\Temp\ccuN1dmO.o:test.c:(.text+0x6c): undefined reference to `DAQmxClearTask@4'

collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

[Done] exited with code=1 in 0.244 seconds`
```

I tried giving path to the DLL like this

```
 PS D:\VSCODES> code --add "C:\Program Files (x86)\National        Instruments\Shared\ExternalCompilerSupport\C\lib32\msvc\NIDAQmx.lib"
```

but its giving error

```
  `code : The term 'code' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,  function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

 At line:1 char:1
 + code --add "C:\Program Files (x86)\National Instruments\Shared  \Extern ...
+ ~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (code:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException`
```

as suggested by one forum, i tried editing my tasks.json file

```
 {
"tasks": [
    {
        "type": "cppbuild",
        "label": "C/C++: gcc.exe build active file",
        "command": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\gcc.exe",
        "args": [
            "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
            "-g",
            "${file}",
            "-o",
            "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            "-LC:\\"C:\Program Files (x86)\National Instruments\Shared\ExternalCompilerSupport\C\lib32\msvc\NIDAQmx.lib"
            "-lNIDAQmx.lib",
        ],
        "options": {
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
        },
        "problemMatcher": [
            "$gcc"
        ],
        "group": {
            "kind": "build",
            "isDefault": true
        },
        "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
    }
],
"version": "2.0.0"
}
```

but this also didn't help

as suggested by answer i tried giving build in VS code terminal

but it returned error

```
PS D:\VSCODES> gcc test.c -o test -L"C:\Program Files (x86)\National    Instruments\Shared\ExternalCompilerSupport\C\lib32\msvc" -lNIDAQmx.lib

gcc.exe: error: .lib: No such file or directory
```

I also changed the Task.json file, but still same error

Comment: Building a C program passes through several separate stages. First there's the compiler which takes the source file and all header files (known as a [*translation unit*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming))) and creates an object file. Then a separate program known as a linker takes all object files and all libraries to create the executable program files. If you want to use a library you need to not only include the header files, but also link with the actual library.

Comment: I understand, can you please help me how to link? im new to VS codes, also did try many documents but no clear idea

Comment: [Using GCC with MinGW](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw). You need to create a `tasks.json` to tell VSCode how to build your project, including the libraries needed to link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try specifying the library path in the command line you use to build the project:

```
gcc test.c -o test -L"C:\Program Files (x86)\National Instruments\Shared\ExternalCompilerSupport\C\lib32\msvc" -lNIDAQmx.lib
```

Also your `tasks.json` file is not well-formed. Could you please try this:

```json
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: gcc.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\gcc.exe",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
                "-LC:\\Program Files (x86)\\National Instruments\\Shared\\ExternalCompilerSupport\\C\\lib32\\msvc\\NIDAQmx.lib",
                "-lNIDAQmx.lib"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

Here is your original `tasks.json` file with additional parameters:

```json
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "C/C++: gcc.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\gcc.exe",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "test.c",
                "-o",
                "test.exe",
                "-LC:\\Program Files (x86)\\National Instruments\\Shared\\ExternalCompilerSupport\\C\\lib32\\msvc\\NIDAQmx.lib",
                "-lNIDAQmx.lib"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

Comment: Hi I tried specifying library path in terminal  i got this error .. PS D:\VSCODES> gcc test.c -o test -L"C:\Program Files (x86)\National Instruments\Shared\ExternalCompilerSupport\C\lib32\msvc" -lNIDAQmx.lib
gcc.exe: error: .lib: No such file or directory
PS D:\VSCODES> gcc test.c -o test -L"C:\Program Files (x86)\National Instruments\Shared\ExternalCompilerSupport\C\lib32\msvc" -lNIDAQmx.lib
gcc.exe: error: .lib: No such file or directory

Comment: I also chaned the task file, still same error, un defined reference

Comment: So you are running `gcc test.c -o test -L"C:\Program Files (x86)\National Instruments\Shared\ExternalCompilerSupport\C\lib32\msvc" -lNIDAQmx.lib` and getting `No such file or directory`? Please check if you have `NIDAQmx.lib` file in `C:\Program Files (x86)\National Instruments\Shared\ExternalCompilerSupport\C\lib32\msvc` directory. If it's there please try to use `-lNIDAQmx` parameter instead of `-lNIDAQmx.lib`.

Comment: '**PS D:\VSCODES> gcc test.c -o test -L"C:\Program Files (x86)\National Instruments\Shared\ExternalCompilerSupport\C\lib32\msvc" -lNIDAQmx**'  dint give me any error
but still if i try to run program it says undefined reference

Comment: Is there a `NIDAQmx.dll` file anywhere? If yes, please try copying it to the working directory and try to run the program.

Comment: Yes NIDAQmx.dll is there in C:\Program Files (x86)\National Instruments\Shared\ExternalCompilerSupport\C\lib32\msvc folder, ok i will copy the file to working folder

Comment: I copied NIDAQmx.dll to workspace, then i could see NIDAQmx.dlllisted in left side of vs codes, but still when i run it says error

Comment: How do you run the program and what is the full error?

Comment: I do run the program from VS codes by right click on the IDE, this is the error ** [Running] cd "d:\VSCODES\" && gcc test.c -o test && "d:\VSCODES\"test
C:\Users\rahul\AppData\Local\Temp\ccmDT6BH.o:test.c:(.text+0x32): undefined reference to `DAQmxCreateTask@8'
C:\Users\rahul\AppData\Local\Temp\ccmDT6BH.o:test.c:(.text+0x5c): undefined reference to `DAQmxStopTask@4'
C:\Users\rahul\AppData\Local\Temp\ccmDT6BH.o:test.c:(.text+0x6c): undefined reference to `DAQmxClearTask@4'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

[Done] exited with code=1 in 0.198 seconds**

Comment: You are running multiple commands at once. Please run them one by one to make sure every single command is running fine.
What is `gcc test.c -o test -L"C:\Program Files (x86)\National Instruments\Shared\ExternalCompilerSupport\C\lib32\msvc" -lNIDAQmx.lib` command writing to console? Do you get the resulting file `test` or `test.exe` built?

Comment: i dono how the resulting file is, im trying to compile and run, so it should be a .exe file right?

Comment: each time when i try to run the program  this cmd is executed by vs codes automatically cd "d:\VSCODES\" && gcc test.c -o test && "d:\VSCODES\"test

Comment: Hi i just figured out that im using code runner to run the program

Comment: I changed the Task file and now the cmd that i run is Executing task in folder VSCODES: C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -g test.c -o test.exe  to make an EXE but still im getting un defined references

Comment: If you are building from VS Code then you need to find the place where this command comes from and update it to include additional parameters. Probably it is `tasks.json` file.

Comment: Yes Editing the Tasks.json corrected the issue